# Play framework Controller method called twice

Tags: java, playframework

There has been a recent issue I am facing with java play framework. A route, set in the routes file, is attached to a method in the controller.

When I am looking at the logs, I see that the method in the controller is being called twice when only one call is made to the server to the attached route.

Is this an issue with the framework?

routes:

```
POST /production/publication/success        controllers.Application.importDataAndUpdate()
```

Application.java

```
Set<String> requestHeader = request().headers().keySet();

Iterator<String> it = requestHeader.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Logger.debug(request().getHeader(it.next()));
}
```

When the payload in the call is big then the logs show that the method in application java is being called twice. Why does this happen?

Comment: You're probably calling it twice from the front-end. Controller methods don't mysteriously get called twice within the framework. This isn't enough information to figure out why. How is this URL used? Form? Ajax call? Something else? What log entries are we talking about? Could something else in your code be calling it internally?

Comment: m-z has a point. I had a chrome plugin for JSON pretty-printing that was reloading the page and ended up with a similar problem. Try using postman or similar to make the call.

Comment: Well a 3rd party system is calling my service and I am logging the call once it reaches my application controller method. The log entries are the entries that are being generated by my service. Nothing in my code is calling this method apart from the route.

Comment: According to your own code you write to log not on each call, but for any value in the header. I would expect to have a lot of writes for one call received.

Comment: I think I kind of realise whats happening, its nothing on my end. I think the 3rd party service is making false calls to my system which is causing this.

Comment: Bit late to the party, but I'm facing the exact same issue. Tried it from postman while ensuring that no other source is connected to my service. Debugged and found identical stack trace for both invocations but postman had triggered only once. Version - Play 2.4.3

Comment: Even I'm facing the same problem when the payload size is big.

Comment: For me it's when http post take too long to reply