# Play framework Scala Controller method called twice

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, twirl

I'm facing an issue while calling a Play Scala controller method with a large amount of data. I have file upload method which takes 2 uploaded files and processes them. If the file size is big, the controller method is getting called twice. If the file size is less, it works fine and is getting called only once. I'm not sure what is happening behind the scene.

routes.conf

```
POST   /test/upload   controllers.TestController.upload(id:Int, isTest: Boolean)
```

TestController.scala

```
def upload(id: Int, isTest: Boolean) = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { implicit request: Request[play.api.mvc.MultipartFormData[play.api.libs.Files.TemporaryFile]] =>
  .....
  .....
}
```

upload.scala.html

```
   @helper.form(action = routes.TestController.upload(form.id, isTest), 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file1">File 1:</label>
        <input class='btn btn-outline btn-primary' name="file1" type="file" data-preview-file-type="text" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="file1">File 2:</label>
        <input class='btn btn-outline btn-primary' name="file2" type="file" data-preview-file-type="text" >
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-primary" id="uploadButton" onclick="$('#myPleaseWait').modal('show');">
        Upload</button>
}
```

Any help on why the method is getting called twice will be helpful.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/30276467/1240268 (but see you've already commented there...) hmm

Comment: Just because you mention the size of the upload makes me wonder if you hit a `maxLength` limit, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaBodyParsers#Max-content-length

Comment: I tried setting play.http.parser.maxDiskBuffer=100MB. But it is still the same.  I had the maxMemoryBuffer and maxLength properties set to 100MB before. The file I'm trying to upload is around 20MB.

Comment: I think the issue is not because of the size. It is because of the time it is taking to process the file. I just commented my file processing logic and uploaded the same file. The controller method gets called only once.

Comment: Are you using any proxy above the server where the play application is hosted? This kind of problem can occur if the request is taking too much of time and it ultimately timesout. Proxy might retry the request based on configuration.

Comment: Play Framework uses Akka HTTP server default. I have not configured any proxy on top of it. But the problem is same as you explained. Not sure what is triggering the request multiple times.

Comment: Same issue here with Play 2.6.1 (http post too long to reply and we observe multiple call of the controller action)

Comment: If the calling method is taking too is taking too much time, try to